# Update ghost on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ghost-blog

I've just started ghost blog on Google cloud, but don't know how to update it using Google Cloud Shell. It's a butnami launch, launched from the Google launcher. I can find any documentation anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/ghost/#how-to-upgrade-ghost

If version > 1.0:

Navigate to `cd /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/htdocs/` then run `ghost update`